# Autoupload of app to apple app store

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes-app

I have a system that I have developed for my company that automatically builds apps. I would like to automatically upload the app with details, artwork and certificates to the app store.

Is there an API for this?

If so can I also promote apps from development to production.

I use this for Android
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/

i need an apple equivalent

Comment: as far as ios is concerned i dont think it is possible . configuring certificates ( production and development ) is different. but once u upload the app . then there is an option .

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/), which is now part of Twitter's [Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/).

Comment: I have had a look and it is a good option. i have also looked at spaceship. on which it is based. would like to build my own so will see what they do and get back to this thread.

Comment: Spaceship is module in Fastlane using Apple Developer Center and the iTunes Connect API as you requested. Hope you find it helpful!